# Why is it is asking for labels to have some other shape?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

Hello I am trying to get an output of an **array of 7 classes**. But when I run my code it says that it expects my data output labels to have **some other shape**. Here is my code -

```py
    def make_model(self):
        self.model.add(InceptionV3(include_top=False, 
                                   input_shape=(self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT, 3), 
                                   weights="imagenet"))
        self.model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
        self.model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

My model compilation and fitment part

```py
    def train(self):
        self.model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss='mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
        self.model.fit(x=x, y=y, batch_size=64, 
                       validation_split=0.15, shuffle=True, epochs=self.epochs, 
                       callbacks=[self.tensorboard, self.reducelr])
```

I get the error -

```py
File "model.py", line 60, in train
    callbacks=[self.tensorboard, self.reducelr])

ValueError: A target array with shape (23639, 7) was passed for an output of shape (None, 6, 13, 7) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Now here it is saying that it expected `(None, 6, 13, 7)` however i gave it labels - `(23639, 7)`

- Now we can clearly see that in the `self.model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))` I have specified 7 as the number of output categories

Here is the model summary -
[image]
So can someone tell me what is wrong here

By the way i did try using `categorical_crossentropy` to see if it makes a difference but it didn't.

In case you wanted the full code -

[Full Code](https://pastebin.com/JFRWz8Ya)

Comment: Use model.summary() to see the actual output shape of your model, you are probably missing a Flatten() before the softmax layer

Comment: ok thanks @Dr.Snoopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the output of the InceptionV3... it returns 4D sequences, you need to reduce the dimensionality before the final dense layer in order to match the target dimensionality (2D). you can do this using `Flatten` or `GlobalPooling` layers.

If yours is a classification problem I also recommend you use `categorical_crossentropy` (if you have one-hot encoded label) or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` (if u have integer encoded labels). `mse` is suited for regression problems